# Powershell : child object edit alters original parent object

Tags: powershell, object

I have a PowerShell multidimensional object called `$foo`.

If I want to edit one specific child object, I can use :

```
$foo[15].Name = 'Something'
```

But I want to edit that child object without editing the parent object.
If I use :

```
$bar = $foo[15]
$bar.Name = 'Something'
```

This still edits the `$foo` parent object.

Why are `$foo` and `$bar` linked ?

Why, when I edit one, does it edit the other ?

Is there anyway to bypass this, so I can edit the subobject without altering the original, parent object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why, when I edit one, does it edit the other ?

Because you're dealing with a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-7.3#43-reference-types), when you do:

```
$bar = $foo[15]
```

Then `$foo[15]` and `$bar` have the same reference, you can tell by using [`[object]::ReferenceEquals($objA, $objB)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-8.0), for example:

```bash
$foo = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{ Name = 'Something' }
    [pscustomobject]@{ Name = 'Something' }
)

$bar = $foo[1]
[object]::ReferenceEquals($foo[1], $bar) # True
```

> Is there anyway to bypass this, so I can edit the sub object without altering the original, parent object ?

Yes there is and the method really depends on the type itself and its depth or complexity, for instance for these simple `pscustomobject`s provided above, they have only one level deep, for them specifically we could use the [`.Copy()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.copy?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-psobject-copy), this would produce a *shallow* copy of the object but in this case it would suffice:

```bash
$bar = $foo[1]
[object]::ReferenceEquals($foo[1], $bar) # True
$bar = $foo[1].PSObject.Copy()
[object]::ReferenceEquals($foo[1], $bar) # False
```

Now `$bar` can be safely updated without updating it's original reference. Other reference types may provide their own cloning implementation, i.e. Hash tables have their own [`.Clone() Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.clone?view=net-7.0). For more complex objects or objects with greater depth, the way around this is via *serialization and deserialization*, the 2 most commonly used methods in PowerShell are Json and CliXml:

```bash
$bar = $foo[1]
[object]::ReferenceEquals($foo[1], $bar) # True

# To and from Json
$bar = $foo[1] | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 | ConvertFrom-Json
[object]::ReferenceEquals($foo[1], $bar) # False

# To and from CliXml
$bar = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($foo[1], 99))
[object]::ReferenceEquals($foo[1], $bar) # False
```